# react-google-maps StandaloneSearchBox unmounting

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to use the StandaloneSearchBox Component from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps

After looking at the [docs](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#standalonesearchbox) and some other answers I implemented the component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withScriptjs } from "react-google-maps";
import StandaloneSearchBox from "react-google-maps/lib/components/places/StandaloneSearchBox";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import API_KEY from "../config/googleAPIkey";

class AddressSearchbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchboxRef = null;
  }

  onSearchBoxMounted = ref => {
    this.searchboxRef = ref;
  };

  onPlacesChanged = () => {
    const places = this.searchboxRef.getPlaces();
    this.props.onPlaceSelect(places[0]);
  };

  render() {

    const Searchbox = withScriptjs(props => (
      <StandaloneSearchBox
        ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
        onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
      >
        <Input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type address or google place name"
          icon="search"
        />
      </StandaloneSearchBox>
    ));

    return (
      <Searchbox
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        onPlacesChanged={this.onPlacesChanged}
        onSearchBoxMounted={this.onSearchBoxMounted}
      />
    );
  }
}

AddressSearchbox.propTypes = {
  onPlaceSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default AddressSearchbox;
```

I use the component in a signup form where all the other input fields update the state on input change causing re-rendering of the whole form.
When the AddressSearchbox component gets re-rendered  it seems that it gets unmounted and then remounts causing flickering. The component itself works fine.

EDIT: When logging the ref parameter passed in onSearchBoxMounted() it prints null and then the SearchBox object after every re-render, so according to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) the SearchBox component gets unmounted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still actual, but to fix this you need to extract this part from the `render` function before your class definition:

```
const Searchbox = withScriptjs(props => (....))
```

So it will look like this:

```
imports ...

const Searchbox = withScriptjs(props => (....))

class AddressSearchbox extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Searchbox .../>
    );
  }
}
```

> In practice, most React apps only call ReactDOM.render() once.
>   Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

You see this flickering because ReactJS runs render() function each time when your state changes.